# How to invert this function? (Inverse exponential function with arctan)

Tags: functions, inverse

How to invert this function?
$$
 y = e^{\arctan(x^5)}
$$

Comment: I mean how to inverse this function, I'm sorry.

Comment: HINT: Exchange x and y and re-arrange. Also note that the domain of the inverse will be restricted due to the trig function.

Comment: Four answers and I'm the only one to up-vote this question.  (Actually, the reason I up-voted it is that it's a nice opportunity to say "What gets done last gets undone first.", which I think is the best way to think about this sort of thing.)

Comment: A point of grammar: "inverse" is a noun; "invert" is a verb.   The English language is rather chaotic about things like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\leftlong}{\longleftarrow\!\shortmid}$
**What gets done last gets undone first:**
$$
\begin{array}{rcccccl}
x & \longmapsto & x^5 & \longmapsto & \arctan(x^5) & \longmapsto & \exp(\arctan(x^5)) = y \\[12pt]
\sqrt[5]{\tan(\log_e y)} & \leftlong & \tan(\log_e y) & \leftlong & \log_e y & \leftlong & y
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 2):

I guess by "solve", you mean "find the inverse $x=f(y)$".

$$y=e^{\arctan(x^{5})}\Leftrightarrow \log{y}=\arctan(x^{5})\Leftrightarrow \tan{(\log{y})}=x^{5}\Leftrightarrow(\tan(\log{y}))^{1/5}=x.$$

Comment: Your last two $\iff$s don't hold. They concern non-injective functions, so the "inverse" will need to pick arbitrary preimages.

Comment: you forgot the last step i.e. switch x and y so the answer is $y = (\tan(\ln(x)))^{\frac{1}{5}}$ [http://www.purplemath.com/modules/invrsfcn3.htm](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/invrsfcn3.htm)

Comment: very helpful! Now I got it, thanks!

Comment: @Lord_Farin The last biconditional holds perfectly well (there is always a fifth root of $x \in \mathbb{R}$), and it's reasonable to assume that the student understands that $\tan(x)$ has to be restricted to a suitable interval. (**Edit:** Whoops, I thought this was recent.)

Answer (score 1):

$${}x=\sqrt[5]{\tan(\log y)}$$